How to address the -ms-high-constrast deprecation message in Edge?
I have got a simple confirmation MatDialog box.
The HTML for this component is:
<h2 mat-dialog-title>{{data.title}}</h2>

<mat-dialog-content>
    <p>{{data.message}}</p>
</mat-dialog-content>

<mat-dialog-actions [align]="'end'">  
    <button mat-raised-button cdkFocusInitial mat-dialog-close [mat-dialog-close]="false">
        {{data.cancelCaption}}
    </button>
    <button mat-raised-button color="primary" [mat-dialog-close]="true">
        {{data.confirmCaption}}
    </button>
</mat-dialog-actions>

Invoked via a service:
confirmDialog(data: ConfirmDialogData): Observable<boolean> {
    return this.dialog
      .open(ConfirmDialogComponent, {
        data,
        width: '490px',
        disableClose: true,
      })
      .afterClosed();
  }

The functionality works as expected. Chrome's console doesn't show this message. However the console in Edge says:
[Deprecation] -ms-high-constrast is in the process of being deprecated. Please see <URL> for tips on updating to the new Forced Colors Mode standard.
I haven't added any custom CSS. So whatever classes are being used are out of the box Angular Material.
What do I need to do in my code so I don't get this deprecation message?


Looks like it is integrated in the component so you won't be able to change that. The deprecation has been pushed forward recently, so has the warning message. Angular Team may have been working on deprecating it now, so that you can expect not to see the deprecation warning in the future release.
Of course, you can submit feedback to them at https://github.com/angular/angular/issues to make them aware of the changes.

Thanks. I submitted a bug report - though its not a bug per se - didn't know how else I could bring this to required attention
